# Android BitmapShader change color

Tags: android, bitmap, shader

I need a little help with the thing that I want to achieve. I'm using `BitmapShader` in my application to draw on a canvas. I'm setting a custom png file as shader to my paint variable and I want to change the color of shader.

Here is an example code which I'm using :

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.particle_point);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    mPaint.setShader(shader);
    ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF , 0x000000FF );
    mPaint.setColorFilter(filter);
```

I find that I can change it's color by using :

`ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF , 0x000000FF );`

, but I need to be able to change it's color by using a custom color picker,which returns color code similar to this : `-234423123`.

So is there any way that I can use this color code and set it as color to my paint variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which color picker are you using?

Comment: I'm using this color picker : http://code.google.com/p/color-picker-view/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color you are getting converted to hex is: FFFFFFFFF206FCAD. So youst need to get rid of the 8 leading Fs:

```
int color = -234423123;//0xFFFFFFFFF206FCAD
int myColor = 0x00000000FFFFFFFF & color;
```

myColor should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little bit more detailed to the Moss's answer. As he suggest you can use `myColor` as the value you want and to set the right value to your shader you have to add `myColor` to your `LightingColorFilter` like this :

```
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(myColor , myColor );
```

And it should work.

Comment: thanks a lot for that answer..i was just trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

To get the hex String:

```
"#"+Integer.toHexString(n));
```

But your color picker just returns the color's int value which should be enough to work with!

```
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF , 0x000000FF );
```

Just change the value which represents the color to the int your colorpicker returns... (without 0x in front of it ofcourse)...

If I ain't wrong this should work just as fine!

Comment: my color picker returns values which looks like -32314112 and something like that. If I set this value as first in my `ColorFIlter` it keep staying black no matter which color I choose.

Comment: Oh, ok looks like this doesn't work with negative values, Moss's solution looks right in that case!